# How can I determine whether a custom environment is followed by a new paragraph?

Tags: spacing

I'm writing a custom command that uses minipages to display its contents:

```
\newcommand{\example}[1]{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}}
```

The spacing around this command should be similar to that of the `align` environment: `\abovedisplayskip` above, and `\belowdisplayskip` after, so I add `\par\vspace{…}` before and after:

```
\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
  \par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
  \par\addvspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
```

This isn't perfect, though: it adds an extra `\parskip` before and after the contents, even if there are no blank lines around the command:

```
AAA % too much space (extra \parskip) after this
\example{\lipsum[1]}
BBB % too much space (extra \parskip) before that
```

I can remove the first one by changing the definition to this:

```
\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
  \ifvmode\else\par\vspace{-\parskip}\fi\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
  \par\addvspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
```

But what's the equivalent fix for the bottom of the command? If I use a negative space the `\parskip` will always be suppressed. Ideally, I'd like text immediately following the command to not be indented, just like with `\[\]`.

**Here's a minimal example:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{50pt}

\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
  \ifvmode\else\par\vspace{-\parskip}\fi\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
  \par\addvspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}

% There should be small spaces after AAA and before BBB
AAA
\example{\lipsum[1]}
BBB

% There should be a large space after AAA and a small one before BBB
% And BBB shouldn't be indented
AAA

\example{\lipsum[1]}
BBB

% There should be a small space after AAA and a large one before BBB
AAA
\example{\lipsum[1]}

BBB
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard way to do this would be to define your environment as a `trivlist`, almost all latex display environments (verbatim, center, quote,..) are defined as trivlists (special one-item version of list) exactly for this reason.

The trivlist code detects whether there is a paragraph break before the list and if so has paragraph spacing before and after, but if there is no paragraph break before the list then the internal `\par` after the list is hidden and paragraph indentation of the following text is suppressed.

`\begin{center}\end{center}` for example is defined by

```
\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax}
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
```

Comment: I believe this just inhibits paragraph indents, but not skips. If you enter `word\begin{center}centred words\end{center}word`, then `\parskip` is still inserted twice.

Comment: @Circumscribe it uses `\partopsep` as `\parskip` in the `\par` case and `\topsep` as `\parskip` in the no-`\par` case, so by setting up those list parameters you can achieve (some) control over that

Comment: @Circumscribe topsep=0pt isn't it? but something like that, yes, this is consistent with all other latex displays so hopefully packages like `\parskip` which set things up for non zero parskip would automatically do the right thing here.

Comment: Sorry, I had deleted my comment (before you had replied, I thought) because I wasn't sure about it anymore. For me setting `\partopsep=\parskip` and 
`\topsep=-\parskip` works. I think both `\parskip` and `\topsep` are always inserted (so this way they cancel out) and `\partopsep` is only inserted when there is a preceding paragraph break.

Comment: @Circumscribe er yes that sounds about right:-)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. But I can only make it work for spaces above the list; it seems that `\trivlist` always puts the same amount of space *after* the list too, regardless of whether the list is followed by a new paragraph. Do you have suggestions for that?

Comment: @Clément yes that's a feature (not clear it's always the optimal design but it is what it is) I think somewhere ther's a package that uses different parameters for the bottom space  (otherwise you'd basically copy trivilist but replace "end" uses of \partopsep by some new \parbottomsep length)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution. 
I'm defining the macro `\tentativepar` which inserts `\par` and sets both `\parskip` and `\parindent` to `0pt`.
It moreover temporarily redefines `\par` and `\everypar` (which is inserted at the start of every paragraph) to reset the original values (and themselves).

The net effect is that `\tentativepar` will insert a paragraph break without any skip or indentation *unless* it is followed by another `\par`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parskip}{50pt}

%% vv We need to store a couple of values
\newskip\savedparskip
\newskip\savedparindent
\newtoks\savedeverypar

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\tentativepar{%
  \par
  \savedparskip\parskip         %% <- store original parskip
  \savedparindent\parindent     %% <- store original parindent
  \expandafter\savedeverypar\expandafter{\the\everypar}
  %% ^^ store original \everypar
  \parskip0pt                   %% <- set parskip to 0pt
  \parindent0pt                 %% <- set parindent to 0pt
  %% vv restore everything that was saved after the first \par
  \def\par{%
    \@restorepar                  %% <- restore original \par
    \expandafter\everypar\expandafter{\the\savedeverypar}%
    \parskip\savedparskip         %% <- reset parskip
    \parindent\savedparindent     %% <- reset parindent
    \par                          %% still insert a paragraph break
  }%
  %% vv or at the stat of the next paragraph
  \expandafter\everypar\expandafter{%
    \the\savedeverypar
    \@restorepar                  %% <- restore original \par
    \expandafter\everypar\expandafter{\the\savedeverypar}%
    \parskip\savedparskip         %% <- reset parskip
    \parindent\savedparindent     %% <- reset parindent
  }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
  \ifvmode\else\tentativepar\fi
  \vspace{\abovedisplayskip}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}%
  \vspace{\belowdisplayskip}
  \tentativepar
}

\begin{document}

AAA
\example{There should be small spaces after AAA and before BBB}
BBB

AAA

\example{There should be a large space after AAA and a small one before BBB. And BBB shouldn't be indented.}
BBB

AAA
\example{There should be a small space after AAA and a large one before BBB}

BBB

CCC

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]