# Use of \gobble inside environment definition

Tags: environments

The following works to create two minipages, side-by-side, using the gobble-user package:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
Some stuff.
\end{minipage}\gobble

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
More stuff.
\end{minipage}
```

I want to automate this by defining two environments:

```
\newenvironment{leftside}
  {\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}}
  {\end{minipage}\gobble}

\newenvironment{rightside}
  {\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}}
  {\end{minipage}}

\begin{leftside}
Some stuff.
\end{leftside}

\begin{rightside}
More stuff.
\end{rightside}
```

This doesn't work--I assume because the \gobble ends up gobbling some part of the implementation of the environment, rather than gobbling the blank line.

Because of the way my TeX file is being created, the only way for me to do this is to define environments to implement it, and I can't seem to avoid the blank line between the two environments, so I need some way to get rid of it to get the two minipages to end up next to each other.  Any ideas?

Comment: `\gobble` is typically used to ignore macro arguments.  I suspect what you want is `\ignorespaces`.  If not, try `\expandafter\gobble}`.

Comment: Probably the answer in [spacing - How can I determine whether a custom environment is followed by a new paragraph? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458433/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-custom-environment-is-followed-by-a-new-paragraph) would address this.

Comment: Actually maybe just use [spacing - Ignore spaces and \par's after an environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179016/ignore-spaces-and-pars-after-an-environment).

Comment: Thanks @user202729--that did the trick!